# Which PHP client library to use with Cassandra?

Tags: php, cassandra

I've tried phpcassa but what about "Cassandra PHP Client Library" or "SimpleCassie"? Which one would be the best choice?

Comment: For what? If you're asking "What's the best ..." ([which is discouraged on SO anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)) the least you could do is give some criteria. What will you be using it for?

Comment: For our web application which is a drug database. We won't abandon Mysql completely but we'd like to move some parts to Cassandra.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*(Since PHPCassa will [no longer be supported](https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa#deprecated) and Pandra [is abandoned](https://github.com/mjpearson/Pandra), this question deserves a new answer.)*

**[DataStax PHP Driver for Cassandra](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver)** is suggested by PHPCassa devs as an alternative that supports CQL, has many excellent features, and is well maintained.

[Github](https://github.com/datastax/php-driver) and [Official website](http://datastax.github.io/php-driver/)

**Update:** It now supports PHP 7

**Update 2 (2019):** It now supports PHP 7.1

Answer (score 5):

I suggest PHPCassa which has

1. An active support group http://groups.google.com/group/phpcassa
2. Nice tutorial on API and Examples @  http://thobbs.github.com/phpcassa/.
3. Provides PHP extension for Thrift Library.
4. Supports all operations as mentioned in Cassandra Wikki
5. Support for [composite types](https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa/blob/master/examples/composites.php) has been added [from version 1.0.a.1]
6. Support for cassandra version 1.0 & 1.1 and thrift version 0.8 is added

Download Link https://github.com/thobbs/phpcassa

Answer (score 1):

In my project I use Pandra : https://github.com/mjpearson/Pandra/wiki and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check out PHP Binary CQL, which is a CQL client that uses the new binary protocol.

Blog post: http://blog.robert.mcfrazier.com/php-binary-cql/

Github: https://github.com/rmcfrazier/phpbinarycql

Disclosure: I'm the author of this library, please feel free to submit pull requests.