# Select X amount of column families in a super column family in Cassandra using PHP?

Tags: php, cassandra

I'm using Kallaspriit's Cassandra/PHP library ( https://github.com/kallaspriit/Cassandra-PHP-Client-Library ).

I'm trying to select the first x amount of column families within the super column family, however, I'm having absolutely no luck, and google searches don't seem to bring up much.

I'm using Random Partitioning, and don't particularly wish to change to OPP as I have read there is a lot more work involved.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not sure abt kallaspriit but have u tried PHPCassa http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401282/which-php-client-library-to-use-with-cassandra/8477276